# Почему нижние элементы grid по высоте меньше, чем самые верхние?

Tags: html, css, css3, css-grid

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему. Нижние блоки отличаются по высоте с верхними. Все блоки должны иметь высоту 350рх, когда нижние составляют, почему то, всего 290рх.  Везде искал решение данной проблемы, но все насмарку.

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cards__spec_list {
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-rows: 350px;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.card__spec {
  background: #e6e7ee;
  border:1px solid green;
}

 li {
  color: #0f5ba7;
}

.card__spec > h2 {
  color: #082a4d;
}

i {
  color: #082a4d;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">

  <div class="cards__spec_list">
  
  
        <div class="card__spec"> 
          <h2 style="color: #082a4d">ИЗОБРАЗИТЕЛЬНОЕ ИСКУССТВО</h2>
            <div class="store__card">
                <strong>Педагогическое образование</strong>
                <br>
                <i style="color: #082a4d">Факультет социально-педагогический</i>
                <br>
                <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
                <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Профессиональное испытание</li>
                <br>
              <p>Очная / Заочная</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card__spec"> 
          <h2 style="color: #082a4d">ИНОСТРАННЫЕ ЯЗЫКИ</h2>
            <div class="store__card">
                <strong>Педагогическое образование (с двумя профилями подготовки)</strong>
                <br>
                <i style="color: #082a4d">Филологический факультет</i>
                <br>
                <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
                <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Профессиональное испытание</li>
                <br>
              <p>Очная</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card__spec"> 
            <h2 style="color: #082a4d">ТЕХНОЛОГИИ СОЦИАЛЬНОЙ РАБОТЫ В РАЗЛИЧНЫХ СФЕРАХ ЖИЗНИДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ</h2>
            <div class="store__card">
                <strong>Социальная работа</strong>
                <br>
                <i style="color: #082a4d">Социально-педагогический факультет</i>
                <br>
                <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
                <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <li style="color: #0f5ba7">История (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Обществознание (ЕГЭ) / Литература (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <br>
              <p>Очная</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
      <div class="card__spec"> 
          <h2>ИЗОБРАЗИТЕЛЬНОЕ ИСКУССТВО</h2>
            <div class="store__card">
                <strong>Педагогическое образование</strong>
                <br>
                <i>Факультет социально-педагогический</i>
                <br>
                <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
                <li>Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <li>Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <li>Профессиональное испытание</li>
                <br>
              <p>Очная / Заочная</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
          <div class="card__spec"> 
          <h2>ИЗОБРАЗИТЕЛЬНОЕ ИСКУССТВО</h2>
            <div class="store__card">
                <strong>Педагогическое образование</strong>
                <br>
                <i>Факультет социально-педагогический</i>
                <br>
                <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
                <li>Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <li>Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
                <li>Профессиональное испытание</li>
                <br>
              <p>Очная / Заочная</p>
            </div>
        </div>
          
          </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Поведение сетки более, чем оправдано тем, что Вы в свойстве `grid-template-rows` указываете размер только для одной (первой) строки. Необходимо, либо явно задать размер для каждой строки, либо воспользоваться `repeat()`, при известном количестве строк.

Если же количество строк заранее неизвестно, то вместо свойства `grid-template-rows` используйте `grid-auto-rows`:

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cards__spec_list {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 350px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.card__spec {
  background: #e6e7ee;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

li {
  color: #0f5ba7;
}

.card__spec>h2 {
  color: #082a4d;
}

i {
  color: #082a4d;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">

  <div class="cards__spec_list">

    <div class="card__spec">
      <h2 style="color: #082a4d">ИЗОБРАЗИТЕЛЬНОЕ ИСКУССТВО</h2>
      <div class="store__card">
        <strong>Педагогическое образование</strong>
        <br>
        <i style="color: #082a4d">Факультет социально-педагогический</i>
        <br>
        <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
        <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Профессиональное испытание</li>
        <br>
        <p>Очная / Заочная</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__spec">
      <h2 style="color: #082a4d">ИНОСТРАННЫЕ ЯЗЫКИ</h2>
      <div class="store__card">
        <strong>Педагогическое образование (с двумя профилями подготовки)</strong>
        <br>
        <i style="color: #082a4d">Филологический факультет</i>
        <br>
        <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
        <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Профессиональное испытание</li>
        <br>
        <p>Очная</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__spec">
      <h2 style="color: #082a4d">ТЕХНОЛОГИИ СОЦИАЛЬНОЙ РАБОТЫ В РАЗЛИЧНЫХ СФЕРАХ ЖИЗНИДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ</h2>
      <div class="store__card">
        <strong>Социальная работа</strong>
        <br>
        <i style="color: #082a4d">Социально-педагогический факультет</i>
        <br>
        <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
        <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <li style="color: #0f5ba7">История (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Обществознание (ЕГЭ) / Литература (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <br>
        <p>Очная</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__spec">
      <h2>ИЗОБРАЗИТЕЛЬНОЕ ИСКУССТВО</h2>
      <div class="store__card">
        <strong>Педагогическое образование</strong>
        <br>
        <i>Факультет социально-педагогический</i>
        <br>
        <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
        <li>Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <li>Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <li>Профессиональное испытание</li>
        <br>
        <p>Очная / Заочная</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__spec">
      <h2>ИЗОБРАЗИТЕЛЬНОЕ ИСКУССТВО</h2>
      <div class="store__card">
        <strong>Педагогическое образование</strong>
        <br>
        <i>Факультет социально-педагогический</i>
        <br>
        <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
        <li>Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <li>Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
        <li>Профессиональное испытание</li>
        <br>
        <p>Очная / Заочная</p>
      </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что ты свойство перепутал: `grid-template-rows` задаёт ряды поштучно, а чтобы задать дефаултное значение для незаданных явно надо использовать `grid-auto-rows`

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 2em 1em 1em 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  gap: .5em;
  width: 8em;
}
  
section::before {
  content: attr(style);
  position: absolute;
  inset: auto 0 100% 0;
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}

div {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<section style="grid-template-rows: 2em">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</section>

<section style="grid-template-rows: 2em 2em">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</section>

<section style="grid-auto-rows: 2em">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</section>

<section style="grid-auto-rows: 2em 1em">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант жёстко можно жёстко задать высоту card_spec.

```css
.section {
  justify-content: center;
}

.cards_spec_list {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.card_spec {
  background: #e6e7ee;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  color: #0f5ba7;
}

.card_spec>h2 {
  color: #082a4d;
}

i {
  color: #082a4d;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    <div class="cards_spec_list">
      <div class="card_spec">
        <h2 style="color: #082a4d">ИЗОБРАЗИТЕЛЬНОЕ ИСКУССТВО</h2>
        <div class="store__card">
          <strong>Педагогическое образование</strong>
          <br>
          <i style="color: #082a4d">Факультет социально-педагогический</i>
          <br>
          <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
          <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Профессиональное испытание</li>
          <br>
          <p>Очная / Заочная</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card_spec">
        <h2 style="color: #082a4d">ИНОСТРАННЫЕ ЯЗЫКИ</h2>
        <div class="store__card">
          <strong>Педагогическое образование (с двумя профилями подготовки)</strong>
          <br>
          <i style="color: #082a4d">Филологический факультет</i>
          <br>
          <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
          <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Профессиональное испытание</li>
          <br>
          <p>Очная</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card_spec">
        <h2 style="color: #082a4d">ТЕХНОЛОГИИ СОЦИАЛЬНОЙ РАБОТЫ В РАЗЛИЧНЫХ СФЕРАХ ЖИЗНИДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ</h2>
        <div class="store__card">
          <strong>Социальная работа</strong>
          <br>
          <i style="color: #082a4d">Социально-педагогический факультет</i>
          <br>
          <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
          <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <li style="color: #0f5ba7">История (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <li style="color: #0f5ba7">Обществознание (ЕГЭ) / Литература (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <br>
          <p>Очная</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card_spec">
        <h2>ИЗОБРАЗИТЕЛЬНОЕ ИСКУССТВО</h2>
        <div class="store__card">
          <strong>Педагогическое образование</strong>
          <br>
          <i>Факультет социально-педагогический</i>
          <br>
          <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
          <li>Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <li>Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <li>Профессиональное испытание</li>
          <br>
          <p>Очная / Заочная</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card_spec">
        <h2>ИЗОБРАЗИТЕЛЬНОЕ ИСКУССТВО</h2>
        <div class="store__card">
          <strong>Педагогическое образование</strong>
          <br>
          <i>Факультет социально-педагогический</i>
          <br>
          <p>Вступительные испытания:</p>
          <li>Обществознание (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <li>Русский язык (ЕГЭ)</li>
          <li>Профессиональное испытание</li>
          <br>
          <p>Очная / Заочная</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```